# Retrieving Data using QueryString with LINQ

Tags: asp.net

how can i use request.querystring in asp.net.  I am trying to retrieve data using Linq but I keep getting errors. Please get back to me Asap. Im still a novice in asp.net 
Code behind:

```
      BlogDBDataContext db = new BlogDBDataContext();

        dynamic q = from b in db.Blogs
                    where b.BlogId = Request.QueryString("BlogId") 
                    select  b;


        lv.DataSource = q;
        lv.DataBind();
```

this give me the error that says : Non-invocable member 'System.Web.HttpRequest.QueryString' cannot be used like a method.

Code behind:
even when I try this code : Request.QueryString["BlogId"]

still it gives me an error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Answer (score 0):

`QueryString` is a `NameValueCollection`, not a method - you should use the `[]` operator to access members:

```
Request.QueryString["BlogId"]
```

Edit: just read the rest of your question. The value of `Request.QueryString["BlogId"]` is a `string`, not an `int`, as the error message suggests. I assume that `b.BlogId` is an `int`, so you need to parse the `string` to an `int` first.

```
BlogDBDataContext db = new BlogDBDataContext();

int blogId;
if (int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["BlogId"], out blogId))
{
    dynamic q = from b in db.Blogs
                where b.BlogId == blogId 
                select b;

    lv.DataSource = q;
    lv.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: I think i've found what i was looking for please check the link : http://forums.asp.net/post/4987401.aspx

Comment: Yes, that will do it too. I prefer using `int.TryParse` instead of `int.Parse` so your app doesn't throw an exception if someone submits a bad request (e.g. `www.example.com/WebPage.aspx?BlogId=a`), but that is a pretty rare case.

Comment: Yet still it throws an error here and it says cannot implicitly convert type int to bool : where b.BlogId = blog

Comment: Oops! I had a typo - `b.BlogId = blogId` should have been `b.BlogId == blogId`. I have fixed my answer now.